# Does requestAnimationFrame run between microstasks?

Tags: javascript, browser, event-loop

Let's say we have a 60Hz refresh rate when the browser does the painting and is supposed to run animation frames with that frequency. If the browser executes multiple microtasks and they (collectively) take more than 1/60 of a second and after that time the microtask queue is still not empty, will it run the `requestAnimationFrame` callback in the meantime or will this callback be blocked until the microtask queue is empty?
In other words: can `requestAnimationFrame` callback run between the execution of microtasks with non-empty microtasks queue?

If the answer is yes then I think I can assume that `requestAnimationFrame` can be a good way to improve app responsiveness when my application runs a lot of microtasks, right?

Comment: @jabaa From how I understand the event loop I believe the fact that JS is single-threaded does not imply that rAF cannot run between microtasks, it only implies that it cannot run during the execution of a single microtask (or during single macrotask or during a sync script)

Comment: @jabaa there is a priority system in the event-loop, the first step of the event-loop is to choose a task among all the possible task-queues. That's where the priority is set. We'll even soon be able to have control over it in the [near future](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6031161734201344). However rAF has a special place in the event loop, it's not a task per se and thus doesn't participate in the prioritization system, it will get called as part of the event loop processing when the monitor sends its VSync signal. So it will slip in even a flow of highest priority tasks.

Comment: However, microtask aren't tasks, and the microtask queue doesn't work like a task queue. It will get emptied entirely before it comes back to the event loop, and new microtask queued during the microtask-checkpoint will also get executed in that same checkpoint. (To be noted, after each rAF callbacks you have a microtask-checkpoint, so you could even rewrite below example with one rAF callback firing before the blocking loop, and another firing after, both would participate in the same "rendering frame").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a simple example proofs that `requestAnimationFrame` will wait

```js
const maxLoops = 10000000
let loopCount = 0

async function loop() {
  loopCount += 1
  if (loopCount >= maxLoops) return 'yes'
  return Promise.resolve().then(loop)
}


Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => loop())
  .then(r => console.log('done', r))
  .catch(console.error)

requestAnimationFrame(() => console.log('animation frame'))
```